# Unable to pull a chain in Emulated Twilight Princess

Tags: dolphin-emulator, zelda-twilight-princess

I'm emulating the Gamecube version of Twilight Princess on Dolphin. I'm currently in the Arbiter's Grounds dungeon. In the first room, you have to use platforms to jump over some quicksand to reach a chain, which you can pull to open the gate nearby that leads to the next room. However, when I attempted to pull the chain, nothing happened. I checked various guides and playthroughs but I haven't seemed to miss anything. I want to know if I'm doing something wrong, is this a gamecube bug, or is it a problem with the emulator.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of the emulator are you using?

Comment: @Juice Version 5.0

Answer (score 3):

I know this was over a year ago, but I encountered the same issue. To fix this, temporarily change your controller settings to the default settings in the dolphin menu, and this should fix it.

Comment: I eventually used cheats to get around this, but I happened to be cosidering replaying Twilight Princess this week! So this is just in time :)

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a problem with your emulator or the rom you are using. Or theres a puzzle there that you are not figuring out.

If it was emulating wii and needed some motion control that might be screwy but since its the NGC version, well an R press is an R press. And if the R button works for something else, no reason why it would suddenly stop working for this application in particular.

EDIT: You have to hookshot this thing, not grab it.

> Make your way to the northeast corner of the room and fight off the small enemy skeleton known as a Stalkin. At the corner of the room you will see a chain, but if you go to grab it, you will sink down below. Instead, use your Clawshot to grab the chain and then pull it back to open the gate. Make your way over to the north side of the room and climb the steps.

https://www.zeldadungeon.net/twilight-princess-walkthrough/arbiters-grounds/

Comment: That is exactly what I did.